# Assign date to dynamically sorted items by number of warehouse locations with reset value

Tags: r, sorting, dynamic-programming, cumsum

In short, I am assigning items for our warehouse team to cycle count every day, but each item may have a different number of locations. I need the total number of locations to be as close to a specific number, say 43 locations a day.

I have a list of all my items I need to count in a quarter with the number of locations. I want to assign a date to each item grouping them as close to 43 locations a day. I would like to have the items counted as randomly as possible, not just items with large number of locations counted in subsequent days. The items with just one location would be nice to save for filling in gaps.

I also can only use workdays, excluding holidays.

As a bonus, if a item has over 43 locations, I'd like to split that into multiple days and use the remainder to be joined with other items if possible.

For sake of ease, let's say we want the number of locations to be 15 per day (a code that could dynamically change that number using a variable would be great.)

Here's a sample:

```
 Item       Loc
 43127      2
 15065      5
 43689      1
 99100      5
 9681352    1
 9680537    1
 10013      1
 55600      3
 43629      1
 PAL001     2
 9950056    1
 467L86     4
 17028      2
 10324      2
 99235REV   12
 LIT003     2
```

With the result being something like this (Really only need Item and Date, but helper columns are okay, too):

```
 Item      Loc  Cum Date
                Sum 
 43127      2   2   3/1/2019
 15065      5   7   3/1/2019
 PAL001     2   9   3/1/2019
 467L86     4   13  3/1/2019
 10324      2   15  3/1/2019
 99235REV   12  12  3/4/2019
 55600      3   15  3/4/2019
 99100      5   5   3/5/2019
 43629      1   6   3/5/2019
 LIT003     2   8   3/5/2019
 17028      2   10  3/5/2019
 43689      1   11  3/5/2019
 9680537    1   12  3/5/2019
 10013      1   13  3/5/2019
 9950056    1   14  3/5/2019
 9681352    1   15  3/5/2019
```

I started using an R loop but can't figure out how to get the date to move around and mark that I've already counted an item.

**Data**

```
test.df <- data.frame(Item=c('43127', '15065', '43689', '99100', 
                               '9681352', '9680537', '10013', '55600', 
                               '43629', 'PAL001', '9950056', '467L86', 
                               '17028', '10324', '99235REV', 'LIT003'), 
                      Loc=c(2, 5, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 12, 2))
```

**Function**

```
spreadDates <- function(df, loc_day) {
  # SPREAD DATES BASED ON LOCATION VALUE
  # Args: 
  #   df: Data Frame with Items and number of locations
  #   loc_day: Number of locations to count per day
  # Returns:
  #   Data Frame with key on new date
  df$Date_Switch <- 0
  df$Cum_Sum     <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (i==1) {                                       
      # First day 
      df[i, 4] <- df[i, 2]                              
      # Cum Sum is no of item locations
    } else {
      if ((df[i - 1, 4] + df[i, 2]) < loc_day) {         
        # If previous cumsum plus today's locations is less than max count
        df[i, 4] <- (df[i - 1, 4] + df[i, 2])            
        # Then add previous cumsum to today's locations
      } else if ((df[i - 1, 4] + df[i, 2]) > loc_day) {  
        # This is where I don't know how to look for next item to count and then 
        # mark it as already counted 
      } else {                                    
        # Previous cumsum plus today=max count
        df[i, 4] <- (df[i - 1, 4] + df[i, 2])          
        # Add previous cumsum to today
        df[i, 3] <- 1                              
        # Make Date_Switch=1 to later change date 
      }
    }
  }
  return(df)
}

test.func <- spreadDates(test.df, 15)
```

If there is a vector way to do this or a package, I'd be fine with that...but I really need a way to automate this as I have thousands of items and have to do this quarterly.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the tradeoffs here? Are you trying to get the optimal solution with the most days possible with exactly 43, or is 42 just about as good, or 44 for that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit: added ideal solution at bottom using `adagio` package: wow!

Here's a quick and dirty attempt that might be good enough. I'm assuming that the optimal daily total locations is 15, but that 14 or 16 are ok. For this first go, I'm not getting too fancy with the shuffling.

BTW, this seems to be a variation of the "multiple knapsack problem" (I just learned this 5 minutes ago), for which there are specialized optimization packages that can approach this with a lot more horsepower.  (For instance: https://rdrr.io/cran/adagio/man/mknapsack.html)

First, I make some larger test data to help evaluate the approach.

```
library(tidyverse)
n = 1000
set.seed(42)
test.df2 <- tibble(
  Item = sample(10000:99999, n, replace = FALSE),
  Loc = sample(c(rep(1:4, 8), 1:12), n, replace = TRUE)  # Most small, some up to 15
)

daily_loc_tgt <- 15   # Here's my daily total target per location
```

### Try 1: Naive assignment

No resorting, just use integer division on cumulative sum. Every time the cumulative total exceeds a multiple of 15, start a new group.

```
baseline <- test.df2 %>%
  mutate(cuml = cumsum(Loc),
         naive_grp  = 1 + cuml %/% daily_loc_tgt) %>%
  group_by(naive_grp) %>%
  mutate(grp_sum = cumsum(Loc)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

How does this perform? For the fake data, looks like about half the time, the groupings are within 1 of 15.

```
eval_soln(baseline)   # Function defined at bottom
```

[image]

### Try 2: Shift overruns down one

This won't eliminate overruns, but will generally reduce them, by assigning them to the next group.

```
shuffle <- test.df2 %>%
  mutate(cuml = cumsum(Loc),
         grp  = 1 + cuml %/% tgt) %>%
  arrange(grp, -Loc) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(grp_sum = cumsum(Loc)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # Shift down overruns
  mutate(grp = if_else(grp_sum > tgt + 1,
                       grp + 1,
                       grp)) %>%
  group_by(grp ) %>%
  mutate(grp_sum = cumsum(Loc)) %>%
  ungroup()

eval_soln(shuffle)
```

This is a modest improvement. Now, about 60% of the groups are close to 15. But there are still a fair number that are far from 15...

[image]

### Try 3: Rely on smart people who solved this decades ago

In googling, I learned this might be called a "multiple knapsack problem," and can be solved more effectively using specialized packages like `adagio`.
https://rdrr.io/cran/adagio/man/mknapsack.html

The only trick was in setting the number of groups in the `k` Capacities section. When I initially set it using 240 (the output of `sum(test.df2$Loc) / 15`), it made R hang longer than I wanted to wait. By bringing that down a bit, it found an exact solution in about 10 seconds, with all 240 groups having 15 Locations.

```
library(adagio)

# p is the "profit" per item; I'll use `Loc`
p <- test.df2$Loc

# w is the "weights", which cannot exceed the capacities. Also `Loc`
w <- test.df2$Loc

# Capacities:  all tgt
k <- rep(tgt, 239)

adagio_soln_assignments <- mknapsack(p, w, k)
adagio_soln <- test.df2 %>%
  mutate(grp = adagio_soln_assignments[["ksack"]]) %>%
  arrange(grp) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(grp_sum = cumsum(Loc)) %>%
  ungroup()
  
eval_soln(adagio_soln)
```

[image]

Voila!

---

Here's the code I used for charting the results:

```
eval_soln <- function(df, tgt = 15, ok_var = 1) {
  stats <- df %>%
    group_by(grp) %>%
    summarize(sum_check = max(grp_sum),
              sum = sum(Loc))
  
  df_name <- substitute(df)
  
  ok_share <- mean(stats$sum >= tgt - ok_var & stats$sum <= tgt + ok_var)
  
  ggplot(stats, aes(sum, 
           fill = sum >= tgt - ok_var  &  sum <= tgt + ok_var)) +
    geom_histogram(binwidth = 1, color = "white") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("gray70", "gray20")) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 30)) +
    guides(fill = FALSE) +
    labs(title = df_name,
         subtitle = paste0("Share of groupings within ", ok_var,
                        " of ", tgt, ": ", 
                        scales::percent(ok_share, accuracy = 0.1)))
}
```